# How to preview win forms design in Visual Studio IDE

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I'm new to Visual Studio, but mostly new to C#. I'm used to coding in Visual Basic. So, this is a step up. I've gotten through a lot of tutorials, and coding isn't the problem.

The problem is... Is there a way to visually see what your forms and windows will look like without having to compile, change, recompile, edit.

I'd much rather be able to actively see the window or form I'm working and coding on before having to debug.

Please someone clue me in if there's a way or an addon. I'm using Visual Studio Pro 2010.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title

Comment: Sorry, C# out of visual studio 2010

Comment: Have you even tried? Create a Windows forms project or a WPF project.

Comment: Double click the form.cs file in the solution explorer.. the designer should open..

Comment: WOW! Thank you, Simon. I was wondering if there was a way, and there is. Thanks ever so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lot of visual studio is drag and drop in terms of building the GUI and then adding some code in the background to make it all function nice.  Here's a tutorial to get you started that I found on YT: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YR6fxe1wa8g